# append text to a radio input the jquery way

Tags: jquery

How do I append text after to a input radio.

this wont work

```
$inp =  $('<input>',
          { 'type': 'radio',
            'id': 'test1',
            'name': 'test' })
         .append('hello radio box <br />');
```

Comment: `input` elements can't have children, so you can't `.append()` something... try `.after()`

Comment: but after can only be used after the radio button has been appended somewhere.

Comment: perfect thanks make it the answer

Comment: @ahren Just edit your answer : `$inp =  $('<input>', { 'type': 'radio', 'id': 'test1', 'name': 'test' }).appendTo(document.body).after('hello radio box ');`

Comment: Just a suggestion, for end-user-friendliness, wrap the text in a label that is `for="test1"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

input elements can't have children, so you can't `.append()` something... try `.after()`

```
$inp =  $('<input>',
          { 'type': 'radio',
            'id': 'test1',
            'name': 'test' })
            .appendTo('body')
            .after('hello radio box <br />');
```

As `dystroy` pointed out, you can't use `.after()` until the element is in the DOM, so you need to `.appendTo()` before.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/dWLtm/

Answer (score 0):

Here is luck!!

**HTML Code:**

```
<input type="radio" name="male" id="male">
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
$(function () {
    // Option: 1
    $('input:radio').after('Your Text Go to Go!!');
    // Option: 2
    $('#test').after('Your Text Go to Go!!');
    // Option: 3
    var textToInsert = "hello radio box <br />";
    var inputAttr = {
            'type' : 'radio',
            'id' : 'test1',
            'name' : 'test'
        };
    $inp = $('<input>', inputAttr).appendTo('body').after(textToInsert);
});
```

There is many dishes, what you like to eat.. :)